# Upgrading React-Native iOS can't find 'Bundle React Native Code And Images' in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have recently upgraded my React-Native version from 0.61.0 to 0.61.2. I use [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.0&to=0.61.2).
Everything is working fine in android and ios simulator but when i give a release build in ios, it says that.

> No bundle url found and crash iOS App.
> Then i compare everything with my previous React-Native version and found that there is no 'Bundle React Native Code And Images' in Xcode root project Build Phase section.

[image]

#React-Native Version Info

```
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470S CPU @ 2.90GHz 
Memory: 4.19 GB / 16.00 GB Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash 
Binaries: Node: 12.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node 
npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm 
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman 
SDKs: iOS SDK: 
Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2 
IDEs: Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild 
npmPackages: react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2 
npmGlobalPackages: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Please someone help me to find out how can i solve this Problem?